# Solving random numbers and random variables from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, equation

```
window.onload = start;
var nr1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
var nr2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
var eq1 = nr1 +"+"+nr2;
var eq2 = nr1 + "-"+ nr2;
var eq3 = nr1 +"*"+ nr2;
var eq4 = nr1 +"/"+ nr2;

var arr = [eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4];
var eq = arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length),Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)];
```

I want to practice something, making a basic Math game. Up there is the code I'm trying to use to generate random numbers and random equations which I want to come out of my html. The reason why I have "" for the operators is because I want the whole equation to come out as a text, I've tried it without the "" marks and I just get the answer straight away.

```
function start() {
document.getElementById("submit").onclick = submitans;
document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = eq;
}
```

this is my startup function which generates the equation. Now this works very well in the html if you look at this photo --
[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7fdV.png). My problem is, I don't know how I'm going to connect the equation to the "if(statement)" from the input box. Because the script reads the commands as text, so it doesn't work even if I write

```
   function submitans() {

    var correct = "Correct!";
    var wrong = "Wrong";      
    var inn = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);

    for (var i = 0; i < eq.length; i++) {
       if(inn === eq[i])
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = "correct";
     }
  }
```

Is there in anyway I can reach the goal I want from this script? I'm sticking with pure javascript, as I am just a beginner, and I really want to learn it. So I'd rather not use jquery.

Aside from this, I'm planning to make my script show the score for every right answer, I thought of having a maximum of 10 right answers for the goal, and the user is allowed to have 5 mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the first snippet of code you can add the answer for each equation

```
var eq1 = nr1 +"+"+nr2;
var eq2 = nr1 + "-"+ nr2;
var eq3 = nr1 +"*"+ nr2;
var eq4 = nr1 +"/"+ nr2;
//answers
var ans1 = nr1 +"+"+nr2;
var ans2 = nr1 + "-"+ nr2;
var ans3 = nr1 +"*"+ nr2;
var ans4 = nr1 +"/"+ nr2;
```

and then when you get the random equation you get the answer for it too

```
var arr = [eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4];
var ansArr = [ans1, ans2, ans3, ans4];
var eqNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length);
var eq = arr[eqNumber];
var ans = ansArr[eqNumber];
```

and edit the last snippet like this

```
function submitans() {
    var correct = "Correct!";
    var wrong = "Wrong";      
    var inn = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);

    //for (var i = 0; i < eq.length; i++) {//delete
       if(inn == ans)
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = correct;
       else
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = wrong;
    //}//delete
 }
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

or instead of all of that you can also only change the last snippet of code like this

```
function submitans() {
    var correct = "Correct!";
    var wrong = "Wrong";      
    var inn = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);

    //for (var i = 0; i < eq.length; i++) {//delete
       if(inn == eval(eq))
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = correct;
       else
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = wrong;
    //}//delete
 }
```

eval will run the text as javascript and it will return the answer of the equation.

Comment: The one with the eval(eq) worked for my code. But the first one that you mentioned didn't, the answer was always wrong. Thanks for the help!

Comment: One more thing i'm wondering, about the division, how can i use toFixed(2) to answer it with just 2 decimal points?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the way you manage the equations... Maybe something like that could be useful :

```
function eq(x, y, op){
    // Find the result depending on the operation
    var res;
    switch (op){
        case: '+':
            res = x + y;
            break;
        case: '-':
            res = x - y;
            break;
        case: '*':
            res = x * y;
            break;
        case: '/':
            res = x / y;
            break;
        default:
            throw "Error";
    }
    // Or something like is more compact
    var res2 = op == '+' ? x+y : op == '-' ? x-y : op == '*' ? x*y : op == '/' ? x/y : null;

    return {
        text: x + op + y,
        res: res
    }
}

// ...
var eq1 = eq(nr1, nr2, '+');
var eq2 = eq(nr1, nr2, '-');
var eq3 = eq(nr1, nr2, '*');
var eq4 = eq(nr1, nr2, '/');
```

Then you just have to display `eq.text` in the HTML and check `eq.res` to compare with the answer... Maybe you can do something nicer but it should work

Answer (score 0):

you can also use eval function to get the answer.
`var answer = eval(document.getElementById("question").innerHTML)` to get the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

`eval()` should work good, try this:

```
function submitans() {
    var correct = "Correct!";
    var wrong = "Wrong";      
    var inn = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);

    if(inn === eval(document.getElementById("question").innerHTML))
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = correct;
    else 
        document.getElementById("input").innerHTML = wrong;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is difference between parseInt and Number

```
var inn = parseInt(document.getElementById("answer").value);
var inn = Number(document.getElementById("input").value);
```

========================

eval() you need to be careful with. more so in how javascript will interpret a given string of

```
var ans1 = eval( 4-3/2*39+3)
```

adding brackets will make sure you get correct result in how you want evel() to return an answer.

```
var ans2 = eval( (4-((3/2)*39))+3 );

var ans3 = eval(document.getElementById("equation").value);
```

will most likely return like ans1, be careful!

to get around issue of above...

```
var eq1a = nr1 +"+"+nr2;
var eq1b = nr1 + nr2
var eq2a = nr1 + "-"+ nr2; 
var eq2b = nr1 - nr2
var eq3a = nr1 +"*"+ nr2;
var eq3b = nr1 * nr2
var eq4a = nr1 +"/"+ nr2;
var eq4b = nr1 / nr2
```

easy enough above.....

taking next step

```
var eq1 = "nr1 + nr2"
var eq2 = "nr1 - nr2"
var eq3 = "nr1 * nr2"
var eq4 = "nr1 / nr2"
```

above is a string that you can do...

```
var nr1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
var nr2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*50);
var eq1 = "nr1 + nr2"
document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = eq1;
//and it will show correctly.
var ans = eval(eq1); 
// and it will give you the answer
```

and taking it one more step further....

```
var eq1 = "((nr1 + nr2) * 4 / 4)"
document.getElementById("equation").innerHTML = eq1.regex();
var ans = eval(eq1);
```

i forgot what needs to be placed in regex() brackets to remove the ( and ) brackets. so it does not print them out to equation html element.

====================

just be careful with eval() if application is critical application. your application could get hacked quickly.

Comment: www.moodle.org php LMS (learning mangament system) there have some various games built into it last time i checked, hangman, scrabble, and like fairly cheap little bitty games. might be something for you,  also kongregate.com there are some "learning" html5 games burried within for typing / spelling and a couple math games.